# Confusion About a Counterexample to a Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

I am currently facing a bit of confusion regarding a counterexample I provided for a statement in my mathematics class. My professor assigned us the task of proving the following statement false by providing a counterexample:

**Statement:** For all sets $S: S \not\subseteq \mathcal{P}(S)$

Here's the counterexample I came up with:

**Counterexample:** Let $S = \{1, 2\}$. In this case, the power set of $S$, denoted as $\mathcal{P}(S)$, is $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$.

Now, if we look at $S$ and $\mathcal{P}(S)$, we can see that $S = \{1, 2\}$ is indeed a subset of its power set, i.e., $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(S)$.

However, my professor provided the following remark: $\{1,2\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ but not a subset, keep looking."

I'm puzzled by this remark because I thought that every set is a subset of its own power set by definition. Could you please help me understand whether my counterexample is incorrect, or if there's something more subtle that I'm missing here? Is my professor mistaken in this case?

I appreciate any clarification or insights you can provide. Thank you

Comment: You say "*we can see that $S=\{1,2\}$ is indeed a subset of its power set*" but this is not the case.  Do you see the **element** $1$ in your power set?  Noting that $1$ is not the same thing as $\{1\}$.  What about $2$?  If you had both the elements $1$ and $2$ in your power set then yes we could say that $\{1,2\}$ is a subset of your power set, but since it has neither this is not the case.

Comment: Do not "*flatten*" elements in your sets.  Being an element of a set is not the same thing as being a subset of the set and so on...

Comment: To show that "For all sets S..." is FALSE, you have to find an $S$ such that $S \subseteq \mathcal P(S)$ [because the negation of "forall ... property" is "there is one ... *negation* of property". But $\emptyset$ is subset of every set.

Comment: For what its worth, you can find nonempty counterexamples $S$ as well.  For example $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.  Read more about [transitive sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set).

Comment: In order for a set to be a subset of it's Powerset, every element of the set needs to be a subset of it. Can you think of such a set? Does ∅ work? What about {∅}? And, {∅, {∅}} ?? Can you see a pattern? For a more "fun" answer, Consider S = {S}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsets and elements are two different things. $S$ is a *subset* of itself, which means that $S$ is an *element* of its own power set. Maybe your professor's remark will be clearer once you understand that distinction.

But there is one set which is a subset of all sets, including the power set of some other set. Can you guess it?

Comment: Yes. It is empty set but it will be trivial wont it?

Comment: @Ameer786: To what does the second “it” refer in your question? The power set of the empty set is not trivial (nor is it empty).

Answer (score -1):

I think we are making a big mistake here. If some set $S$ is a subset of another set $P$ then the set $S$ should have at least one element of $P$ in it. In your example it is seen that $P$ has an element $\{1,2\}$ in it as an element. If you look closely there is no element in the set $P$ that is also present in the set $S$. The confusion arose from the fact that $\{1\}$ is not same as the element $1$. When an element is covered by a set of curly bracers it becomes a set and not an element.